# MySQL - Get maximum Tuple without Grouping everything

Tags: mysql

I need some help by writing a SQL statement.

I have a table (it's already a result from another query) with 4 columns e.g.:

Firstname | Lastname | Softwarename | Hours

With a example data set like:

Row1: Max | Huber | Word | 25h

Row2: Max | Huber | Excel | 12h

The result of the query should be the first row.
My problem is that I am forced to add the Softwarename to the group by, but when I do that the result is obviously incorrect.

How do I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you (at last) correctly, I think you want something like this (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=71edb392c30dbff23e9ee8b8b5c76c9a)):

Create your table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_tab
(
  first_name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
  last_name  VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
  soft_name  VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
  soft_hours VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL
);
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES ('Max', 'Huber', 'Word',  '25h');
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES ('Max', 'Huber', 'Excel', '15h');

INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES ('Felix', 'TheCat', 'Outlook', '35h');
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES ('Felix', 'TheCat', 'Word',  '25h');
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES ('Felix', 'TheCat', 'Excel', '15h');

INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES ('Donald', 'Duck', 'Excel', '20h');
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES ('Donald', 'Duck', 'Word',  '8h');
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES ('Donald', 'Duck', 'Outlook', '3h');
```

And use the following **premliminary** SQL (included to demonstrate the thought processes that went into formulating the answer. I find that people learn better if they can see a "breadcrumb trail" (cf. Hansel and Gretel)):

```
SELECT
  first_name,
  last_name,
  MAX(CAST(soft_hours AS UNSIGNED)) AS use_duration
FROM test_tab
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
ORDER BY last_name;
```

The `CAST` is [necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268248/how-to-get-only-digits-from-string-in-mysql) because of the inclusion of the `h`in the string for the duration of usage (much better to use a plain `INTEGER`). If the `CAST` isn't present, `8h` will be "greater than" `20h` for Donald Duck when sorted as a character string - `CAST`ing to `UNSIGNED` removes that problem.

Result:

```
first_name  last_name   use_duration
    Donald       Duck             20
       Max      Huber             25
     Felix     TheCat             35
```

Having obtained the `first` and `last` names and the `use_duration`, we are now in a position to `JOIN` back to our original table this way:

```
SELECT 
  t1.first_name, t1.last_name, t1.soft_name, 
  CAST(t1.soft_hours AS UNSIGNED) AS "usage"
FROM test_tab t1
JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    first_name,
    last_name,
    MAX(CAST(soft_hours AS UNSIGNED)) AS use_duration
  FROM test_tab
  GROUP BY first_name, last_name
) AS t2
ON t1.first_name = t2.first_name AND t1.last_name = t2.last_name
AND CAST(t1.soft_hours AS UNSIGNED) = t2.use_duration
ORDER BY t1.last_name;
```

Result:

```
first_name  last_name   soft_name   usage
    Donald       Duck       Excel      20
       Max      Huber        Word      25
     Felix     TheCat     Outlook      35
```

Now, I would recommend that you keep the duration as just a pure `INTEGER` rather than use 25h. I hope this responds to your needs, - if not, then please expand on your explanation and I'll endeavour to revise my answer to your satisfaction. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)